# How to get Apache spark to ignore dots in a query?

Tags: java, json, apache-spark

Given the following JSON file:

```
[{"dog*woof":"bad dog 1","dog.woof":"bad dog 32"}]
```

Why does this Java code fail:

```
DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().json("dogfile.json");
df.groupBy("dog.woof").count().show();
```

but this not:

```
DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().json("dogfile.json");
df.groupBy("dog*woof").count().show();
```

This is a snippet of the failure:

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'dog.woof' given input columns: [dog*woof, dog.woof];
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:334)
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because dots are used to access attributes of the `struct` fields. You can escape column names using backticks:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json(sc.parallelize(Seq(
   """{"dog*woof":"bad dog 1","dog.woof":"bad dog 32"}"""
)))

df.groupBy("`dog.woof`").count.show
// +----------+-----+
// |  dog.woof|count|
// +----------+-----+
// |bad dog 32|    1|
// +----------+-----+
```

but using special characters in the names is not a good practice and work with in general.