# Extract json data in Spark/Scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have a json file with this structure

```
root
 |-- labels: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- compute.googleapis.com/resource_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- container.googleapis.com/namespace_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- container.googleapis.com/pod_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- container.googleapis.com/stream: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to extract the four `.....googleapis.com/...` into four columns.

I tried this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df = df.withColumn("resource_name", df("labels.compute.googleapis.com/resource_name"))
       .withColumn("namespace_name", df("labels.compute.googleapis.com/namespace_name"))
       .withColumn("pod_name", df("labels.compute.googleapis.com/pod_name"))
       .withColumn("stream", df("labels.compute.googleapis.com/stream"))
```

I also tried this, making the `labels` an array which has solved the first error that it said the sublevels are not `array` or `map`

```
df2 = df.withColumn("labels", explode(array(col("labels"))))   
        .select(col("labels.compute.googleapis.com/resource_name").as("resource_name"), col("labels.compute.googleapis.com/namespace_name").as("namespace_name"), col("labels.compute.googleapis.com/pod_name").as("pod_name"), col("labels.compute.googleapis.com/stream").as("stream"))
```

I still get this error

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: No such struct field compute in compute.googleapis.com/resource_name .....
```

I know `Spark` thinks that each dot is a nested level, but how I can format `compute.googleapis.com/resource_name` that `spark` recognises as a name of the level rather than a multilevel.

I also tried to solve as stated here

[How to get Apache spark to ignore dots in a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619324/how-to-get-apache-spark-to-ignore-dots-in-a-query)

But this also did not solve my problem. I have labels.compute.googleapis.com/resource_name, adding backticks to the compute.googleapis.com/resource_name still gives same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Apache spark to ignore dots in a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619324/how-to-get-apache-spark-to-ignore-dots-in-a-query)

Comment: Thanks for flagging the relevant question. But this did not solve my problem that is why I asked the question. I have `labels.compute.googleapis.com/resource_name`, adding backticks to the `compute.googleapis.com/resource_name` still gives same error.

Comment: @ZmnakoAwrahman, backticks in the right places do work, the snippet in my answer run just fine in my experiment, see update for the full example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use back apostrophe *`* to isolate the names that contain special characters like '*.*'. You need to use backtick after the **labels**, as it is parent tag.

```
val extracted = df.withColumn("resource_name", df("labels.`compute.googleapis.com/resource_name`"))
    .withColumn("namespace_name", df("labels.`container.googleapis.com/namespace_name`"))
    .withColumn("pod_name", df("labels.`container.googleapis.com/pod_name`"))
    .withColumn("stream", df("labels.`container.googleapis.com/stream`"))

  extracted.show(10, false)
```

Output:

```
+--------------------+-------------+--------------+--------+------+
|labels              |resource_name|namespace_name|pod_name|stream|
+--------------------+-------------+--------------+--------+------+
|[RN_1,NM_1,PM_1,S_1]|RN_1         |NM_1          |PM_1    |S_1   |
+--------------------+-------------+--------------+--------+------+
```

**UPDATE 1**
Full working example.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val j_1 =
  """
    |{ "labels" : {
    |   "compute.googleapis.com/resource_name" : "RN_1",
    |   "container.googleapis.com/namespace_name" : "NM_1",
    |   "container.googleapis.com/pod_name" : "PM_1",
    |   "container.googleapis.com/stream" : "S_1"
    |             }
    |}
  """.stripMargin

  val df = spark.read.json(Seq(j_1).toDS)
  df.printSchema()

  val extracted = df.withColumn("resource_name", df("labels.`compute.googleapis.com/resource_name`"))
    .withColumn("namespace_name", df("labels.`container.googleapis.com/namespace_name`"))
    .withColumn("pod_name", df("labels.`container.googleapis.com/pod_name`"))
    .withColumn("stream", df("labels.`container.googleapis.com/stream`"))

  extracted.show(10, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the columns (or sublevels), then do the `withColumn`

```
val schema = """struct<resource_name:string, namespace_name:string, pod_name:string, stream:string>"""
val df1 = df.withColumn("labels", $"labels".cast(schema))
```

Comment: What will happen in case of the schema evolution, for example due to some changes in the source system the order of fields: "compute.googleapis.com/resource_name" and "container.googleapis.com/pod_name" changes? This approach will not work properly and will not alert of the change, that can mess up the data flow.